# IIS URL rewrite dynamic number of folders

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have to create a rewrite rule that catches all URLs from the old shop system and redirect them to the new shop. The problem is the following:

The source URL from the old shop can contain the path where you did find the product number, looks like this: `www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/[product number].html`

folder1, folder2 and folder3 can, but don't need to be in the called URL. They also are not fixed (**e.g. folder1 can be "cars" or "bikes" or "services"**). The link could also be `just www.domain.com/folder1/[product number].html` or even www.domain.com/[product number].html sometimes.

For the new system, I only need the [product number] in my target URL. Should look like this: `www.domain.com/path1/path2/[product number].aspx`

I could not find anything in Google or Stackoverflow that helped me with this.

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Comment: Is the product number always numeric?

Comment: No, the product number is alphanumeric and can include - and _ characters

Comment: What's the relation between folder1, folder2 and path1, path2 ? Are the paths dynamic too?

Comment: folder1-3 describe the product catalog path used in the old magento shop. I do not need them in the new shop system and URL any more.

Comment: If I'm at (old site) `www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/[product number].html` how do I know what version of `www.domain.com/path1/path2/[product number].aspx` to rediect the user to?

Comment: The new URL is always static except the product number. `path1` and `path2` do never change, they are not related to the old URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Three deep" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*/.*/.*/(.*?).html" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/path1/path2/{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Two deep" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*/.*/(.*?).html" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/path1/path2/{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="One deep" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*/(.*?).html" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/path1/path2/{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="None deep" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*?).html" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/path1/path2/{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I am worried that the expression - `(.*?)` - I'm using for the product code is *too* catch all, but I don't know the structure of your product codes. If you could tighten it up, it'd be better.

I'm also worried that they will hit things that aren't products (e.g. category and search) so if there is a pivot point that all product URLs use, I'd recomend using that. Tightening the product code bit will probably help false matches too.

At the moment it's working on the .html vs .aspx being the bit that isn't sending it into a redirect spiral.

I can probably do it in less rules with a better regex, which I'll have a bash at tonight.